Sub-differential at a point, nonlinear optimization
I've got some difficulties with computing the sub-differential.
I've got the following exercise:
Consider the problem to
$$
\begin{cases}
\text{minimize } -x_1 \\
\text{subject to }\\ (x_1+1)^2+x_2^2 \leq 1\\
x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
Lagrangian relax the first constraint, and derive the dual function $q(\lambda)$. What is the sub differential of $q$ in the point $\lambda=1/4$?
Def: (Sub gradient):
Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty convex set and let $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Then $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a $\textbf{subgradient}$ of $f$ at $\bar{x} \in S$ if
$f(x) \geq f(\bar{x}) + p^T(x - \bar{x}), \quad \text{for any } x \in S.$
Def: (Sub differential):
The set of all subgradients to $f$ at $\bar{x}$, called the $\textbf{subdifferential}$ of $f$ at $\bar{x}$, is defined as
$\partial f(\bar{x}) = \left\{ p \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) \geq f(\bar{x}) + p^T(x - \bar{x}), \, \text{for all } x \in S \right\}.$
My solution so far:
1. Relax the first constraint
This gives me $L(x,\mu) = -x_1 + \mu((x_1+1)^2+x_2^2-1)$
subject to $x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq 1$, $x,\mu \geq 0$
2. Derive the dual function
Dualfunction $q(x,\mu) = inf_x \ L(x, \mu)$
Derivate of Lagrangian w.r.t $x_1,x_2$ set to zero to find inf and we get that $$q(\mu)=3-\frac{3}{\mu}-2\mu+\frac{1}{4\mu^2}$$
3. Expressing subgradient and sub-differential
At this point I have some troubles actually using the definition to express my dual function of $\mu$ at $1/4$, and would really like to get some help in this step. There more, the more grateful I am. This is a new topic to me, so please be understanding :)
